# Exception(checked and unchecked)

Tags: java

There are 2 types of exceptions. Checked and unchecked. Checked is defined as an exception that occurs at compile time and unchecked is an exception caught at runtime. Usually an exception is always caught at runtime. So how is it possible that checked exception is caught at compile time.

Comment: The compiler doesn't **catch** an exception at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

> So how is it possible that checked exception is caught at compile time.

The compiler can check  if the method or constructor that is being called has been *declared* to throw a checked exception which is information that *is* available to the compiler at compile time. With this information, the compiler can check to see if the calling code either throws or catches the exception and then give an error if this is not occurring.

Note that the exception may or may not be thrown, but only during run-time, and so it is only truly fully handled at run-time, if it occurs.